# Writing a Parser for mixed Languages

Tags: parsing

I am trying to write a Parser that can analyze mixed Languages and generate an AST of it. I first tried to build it from scratch on my own in Java and failed, because this is quite a hard topic for a Parser-beginner. Then i googled and found http://www2.cs.tum.edu/projects/cup/examples.php and JFlex.

The question now is: What is the best way to do it?

For example i have a Codefile, that contains several  Tags, JS Code, and some $CMS_SET(x,y)$ Code.  Is the best way to solve this to define a grammar for all those things in CUP and let CUP generate a Parser based on my grammer that can analyze those mixed Language files and generate and AST Tree of it?

Thanks for all helpful answers. :)

EDIT: I need to do it in Java...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic is quite hard even for an expert in this area, which I consider myself to be; check my bio.

The first issue is to build individual parsers for each sublanguage.  The first thing you will discover is that defining parsers for specific languages is actually hard; you can read the endless list of SO requests for "can I get a parser for X" or "how do I fix my parser for X".  Mostly I think these requests end up not going anywhere; the parsing engines aren't very good, you have to twist the grammars and the parsers to make them work on real languages, there isn't any such thing as "pure HTML", the standards documents disagree and  your customer always has some twist in his code that you're not prepared for.  Finally there's the glitches related to character set encodings, variations in newline endings, and preprocessors to complicate the parsing parsing problem.  The C++ preprocessor is a lot more complex than you might think, and you have to have this right.  The easiest way to defeat this problem is to find some parser generator with the languages already predefined.   ANTLR has a bunch for the now deprecated ANTLR3; there's no assurance these parsers are robust let alone compatible for your purposes.

CUP isn't a particularly helpful parser generator; none of the LL(x) or LALR(x) parser generators are really helpful, because no real langauge matches the categories of things they can parse. The consequence: an endless stream of requests (on SO!) for help "resolving my shift-reduce conflict", or "eliminating right recursion".    The only parser generator IMHO that has stood the test of time is a GLR parser generator (I hear good things about GLL but that's pretty recent).  We've done 40+ languages with *one* GLR parser generator, including production IBM COBOL, full C++14 and Java8.

You second problem will be building ASTs.  You can hand code the AST building process, but that gets old fast when you have to change the grammars often and/or you have many grammars as you are effectively contemplating.  This you can beat your way throught with sweat.  (We chose to push [the problem of building ASTs into the parser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1916687/120163) so we didn't have to put any energy this in building a grammar; to do this, your parser engine has to offer you this help and none of the mainstream ones do.).

Now you need to compose parsers. You need to have one invoke the other as the need comes up; of course your chosen parser isn't designed to do this so you'll have to twist it.    The first hard part is provide a parser with clues that a sublanguage is coming up in the input stream, and for it to hand off that parsing to the sublangauge parser, and get it to pass a tree back to be incorporated in the parent parser's tree, presumably with some kind of marker so you can tell where the transitions between different sublangauges are in the tree.  You can often do this by hacking one language's lexer, when it sees the clue, to invoke the other; but then what you do with the tree it returns?  There's no way to give that tree to the current parser and say "integrate this".  You get around this by modifying the parsing machinery in arcane ways.

**But all of the above isn't where the problem is.**

Parsing is inconvenient, but only a small part of what you need to analyze your programs in any interesting way; you need symbol tables, control and data flow analysis, maybe points-to analyses, and the engineering on these will swamp the work listed above.   See my essay on "Life After Parsing" (google or via my bio) for a long discussion of what else you need.

In short, I think you are biting off an enormous task in just "parsing", and you haven't even told us what you intend to do with the result.    You are welcome to start down this path, but very few people have succeeded;  my team spent over a 50 man years of PhD level engineering to get where we are, and we are hardly done.

Java won't make the solution any easier or harder; the langauge in which you solve all of the above is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for the quite detailed answer. I want to parse a mixture of different language's code to be able to autoformate it correctly. So by parsing it into an AST, i can easily format it by just indenting each node by it's level * tab. Also since im a medical informatics Student (bachelor) and quite bored at my 3rd Semester i want to use this to actually learn something. My ultimate goal for this little project is to have a parser that detects each CodeNode and parses it into a tree independent of the languages mixed. After that i can easily be formatted.

Comment: I do not have any experience with parser, but i want to learn more about it. As i said i tried doing it on my own and wrote a little "Parser" in Java, that is able to handle easy tags of the Type <xy></xy> but cannot do more than that.

Comment: If your *only* goal is formatting, then you don't have the life-after-parsing problem.   You still have the problems of defining and composing the parsers. If you want to learn about "autoformatting", see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5834775/120163